# using loop variable in text string for loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop

If i have multiple csv files stored as:
m1.csv, m2.csv,.....,m50.csv and what I would like to do is load each csv into R, run the data in the i-th file and store it as a variable: m'i'. I am trying to use a for loop but i'm not sure if i can quite use them in such a way. For example:

```
for (i in 1:100){
     A<-as.matrix(read.csv("c:/Users/Desktop/m"i".csv))
     ...
     #some analysis on A
     ...
     m"i"<- #result of analysis on A
     }
     V<-cbind(m1,m2, .... ,m100)
```

Comment: You'll need to use `paste0` to assemble paths and names, and probably `assign` instead of `<-`, as your name will be quoted, but yes, the approach is pretty common. You won't want to do analysis in the loop, though; save that for later. You may also want to save them into a list—instead of the global environment—to make looping over them later easier. It also simplifies naming.

Comment: @alistaire While I can agree that OP's approach is pretty common, I don't think it can be considered "correct" and it shouldn't be encouraged. The use of `assign` is almost never a good idea. A simple `lapply` would solve OP's task in a cleaner way.

Comment: That is why God created [lists](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
filenames = list.files(getwd())
filenames = filenames[grepl(".csv",file_names)]
files = lapply(filenames, read.csv)
files = do.call(rbind,files)
```

Comment: The idea is good, but there are some inaccuracies. 1) No need to call `list.files`, since in the OP the file names are specified: `filenames<-paste0("c:/Users/Desktop/m",1:100,".csv")` should be the way. 2) The analysis part is missing: OP should define a function (let's call it `makeAnalysis`) that does the task. 3) At the end, OP wants to `cbind` rather than `rbind`. A simple line should be `do.call(cbind,lapply(filenames, function(x) makeAnalysis(read.csv(x))))`.

Comment: @nicola I've written up a function as you recommended, im just wodnering if i want to add the parameter row.names=1 to read.csv where should i do that? it seems to give me an error if i put it in the do.call

Comment: @nicola further, as my function involves matrix calculations, i get the non-conformable arguments error, not quite sure how to deal with this

Comment: @dimebucker91 Arguments of `read.csv` should go into the `read.csv` call. For instance, in my line you should replace `read.csv(x)` with `read.csv(x,row.names=1)`. For the second issue, I suspect that it's a bug of your function and cannot tell for sure to what it is due. It seems that you are trying to make a matrix product between matrices with wrong numbers of row or cols.

Comment: @nicola I tried putting it there, i get the error: unused argument (rownames=1), even when trying it out with just lapply(filenames,function(x) makeanalysis(read.csv(x,rownames=1)))

Comment: @dimebucker91 Please, check what you wrote. Once it's `row.names` and the other `rownames`. The error message was clear, you should have solved it by yourself.

Comment: @nicola silly mistake.. i fixed my other issue by using as.matrix(read.csv...) and that works out now, if you put your suggestions in an answer i can mark it as correct, thanks again!